# How can nitrogen be quadruply bonded in tris(8-hydroxyquinoloinato)aluminum?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, lewis-structure

Nitrogen typically has five outer valence electrons. So how does a triply-bonded nitrogen in 8-hydroxyquinoline end up quadruply bonded in [tris(8-hydroxyquinolinato)aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tris(8-hydroxyquinolinato)aluminium)?

Comment: Ever heard of a [coordinate bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_covalent_bond)?

Comment: It may be easier to first understand a simpler system, particularly the [pyridinium cation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyridinium).

Comment: Come to think of it, why not start with _ammonium_  cation?